# control which version of PostgreSQL starts

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, startup-scripts

I have three versions of Postgres (8.4, 9.0, 9.1) running on my Ubuntu box.  Each version is configured to listen on a different port.  When I reboot the machine, only the 9.0 version starts automatically.

I can start the other versions manually via "sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start 9.1", but I can't figure out where the configuration is that passes the parameter into the script when the server is booting.

Someone out there must know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit `/etc/postgresql/$version/$clustername/start.conf`.  That file should be well self-documented